# Refresh an image in the browser every x milliseconds

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

I have a server (**AWS instance**), which spits out an image file `test.png` every, say, 10ms.

I also have a webpage on the server called, say, `index.html`.
Within that `index.html`, I have an image tag whose `src="test.png"`.

Now, what I want to do is refresh that image (`test.png`) every 10ms.
I know I can do this a number of ways:

- Use JS to reload the page (`location.reload();`)
- Use JS to update the src attribute (`setInterval(refresh(),10); //with timestamp` to force
  browser to reload - not from cache)
- Use JS and Ajax to hit the server for an image URL Use an HTML meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh"
  content="5" />`
- etc...

The trouble with these approches is that:

A) If the refresh time is less than 250ms, the image does not update

B) The image flickers

**Question:**
How can I make the image refresh every 10ms (or less! faster is better...), without flickering? Looking for some ideas.

**Edit**

I have tried using setTimeout, as suggested by @tripleb, but there is no difference, that I can tell.

```
function refresh(){
   //update src attribute with a cache buster query
   setTimeout("refresh();",10)
}

refresh();
```

Comment: More efficient or specifically resolve the issues?  I can think of ways to resolve these issues but couldn't characterize them as more efficient.

Comment: @JECarterII Thanks, I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: loading an image every `10ms` means that the client to server and back to client connection should be as fast as localhost all throughout the request.

Comment: @Deadpool 10ms was an example. Anything up to about 30ms should be fine ;) .

Comment: @pookie `30ms` is still too fast. In `30ms` the server would already receive 33 requests in just 1 second from 1 user. And on the client side, if the requests somehow returned properly without any delay the effect of updating an image every `30ms` would make a lot of images just being overridden without making any impact to visual appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second method would be the best your issue is probably that you are using setInterval, this not really a good method as it always executes ignoring if the previous call is ready or not. That is probably why for small timeouts it just "locks" try

```
function refresh(){
   //update src attribute with a cache buster query
   setTimeout("refresh();",10)
}
refresh();
```

a recurring function will not start a new refresh until the first is complete.

P.S. 10 milliseconds is probably WAY to fast for any real world application

UPDATE: 10 mils is way to fast for the browser to render however you gen just get the browser to update as fast as it possibly can by doing this:
http://jsfiddle.net/zdws1mxv/

Comment: Agreed on the 10 ms - if streaming is what is needed, maybe feed a player like flow player from an rtmp that is generated at the server.

Comment: Right, I will give setTimeout a go.  @JECarterII, you are correct (streaming).

Comment: Okay, tried this. Unfortunately, there is no difference that I can tell. The timeout still needs to be equal to or greater than 250ms before the image gets updated.

Comment: You're right. Although it is not perfect, it is as good as it is going to be without implementing streaming, which I will do at a later point in time. Thank you, this is far faster and works.

Answer (score 0):

How about asigning a random `Math.random()` to the end of the url and just using a setInterval to call and replace the image with a new random again every 10ms, the 10ms is very fast though. like they said above. Im not sure the purpose of this.

Example

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://img2.fotoalbum.virgilio.it/v/www1-3/176/176513/304872/IMG_0880-vi.jpg" id="myImage" />
```

**JS**

```
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = 'http://img2.fotoalbum.virgilio.it/v/www1-3/176/176513/304872/IMG_0880-vi.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();

setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
    myImageElement.src = 'http://img2.fotoalbum.virgilio.it/v/www1-3/176/176513/304872/IMG_0880-vi.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
    console.log(myImageElement);
}, 10);
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/11fk17ck/1/

In fact, 4ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2) , the minimum timeout value for nested timeouts was 10 ms.

hope this helped someone

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried this as I mention in my question: Use JS to update the src attribute (setInterval(refresh(),10); //with timestamp to force browser to reload - not from cache)

Using timestamp is a similar technique to using random - I've tried both ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the setInterval() method of the jquery to add the time interval. It takes interval in milisecond as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How about streaming? You can use node.js to push image data to client via web socket.

Comment: Please elaborate a little if you can ;) Neither node.js nor web sockets are something that I am familiar with.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with SO editor. I've tried to add some code but it does not work for me. I don't know why other can post long answer but I just have 500 chars :(

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, 10ms (1/100th of a second) is a bit quick for the mechanisms you are trying to use.  Consider that full motion video is typically 30 frames per second (100 frames per second would be high speed video playback, not something a browser will well support by just pushing image requests).

Since it sounds like what you want to accomplish is streaming video, I can recommend the following as what we use here:

Streaming video source: https://obsproject.com/  Open Broadcast Project - you can use a variety of methods offered by this platform to produce a video stream.  You can produce an rtmp stream with this.

Nginx Web Server: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/ - handles rtmp streams very well.

Flowplayer: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html - we put this on the nginx box and embed it in a web page served from there.